# (react) debounce with arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to debounce a function (using underscore's debounce) passed as a prop to a component. I've been able to do this in the past with the following:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.handleInputTextChangeDebounced = debounce(() => {
      console.log('I debounce!');
    }, 250);
  },
```

That works fine and dandy, but now I need to access the event argument (so I can get the value from the input) from the onChange which triggeres the `handleInputTextChangeDebounced`

e.g.:

```
  <input onChange={this.handleInputTextChangeDebounced} data-option='buildNumber' />
```

I can't simply use a ref because I have many form input options that I want to use with thise debounced function.

I tried to return the debounce as a function within the handleInputTextChangeDebounced which would receive the event, but that appears to stop the debouncing from working.

Suggestions?

Comment: What is `debounce`? Does it forward passed arguments to its callback?

Comment: I second @zerkms comment. Any useful debounce should call your anonymous function passing the event.

Comment: sorry I didn't mention - I've been using underscore's debounce http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: if I try to pass something with debounce `debounce((e) => {` I get the synthetic event object, but all properties are null

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution using two steps. I called a normal class function (`handleInputTextChange`) where I extracted the value from the input field, then I called the debounced function (`handleInputTextChangeDebounced`) separately.

```
handleInputTextChange(e) {
  this.handleInputTextChangeDebounced(e.target.value);
},

handleInputTextChangeDebounced: debounce((value) => {
  // do debounced stuff with value here...
}, 700),


<input onChange={this.handleInputTextChange} type='text' data-option='buildNumber' />
```